# How to capitalize the first letter of a string and lowercase the rest in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell

I have to write a function which uppercase the FIRST letter of a string and also LOWERCASE the rest of the string (This string contains random uppercased or lowercased letters).

So far, I have managed to do this:

```
capitalised :: String->String
capitalised [] = []
capitalised x
            | length x == 1 = map toUpper x
            | otherwise = capitalised (init x): map toLower (last x)
```

and all other sort of weird functions, and I still could not figure it out.

Please help! Tx in advance!

Forgot to mention, the problem states that I need to write a recursive solution!

Comment: Please, don't post homework problems here...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Remember that a `String` is just a type synonym for `[Char]`? Here we utilize that:

```
import qualified Data.Char as Char

capitalized :: String -> String
capitalized (head:tail) = Char.toUpper head : map Char.toLower tail
capitalized [] = []
```

Here is a recursive version:

```
capitalized :: String -> String
capitalized [] = []
capitalized (head:tail) = Char.toUpper head : lowered tail
  where
    lowered [] = []
    lowered (head:tail) = Char.toLower head : lowered tail
```

Comment: This should be the most concise and correct(and fast) answer to my question. I have to appreciate your help a lot. However, I forgot to mention some keywords in my question. The funct should be written recursively. Is there a solution to do just that? TXX!

Comment: So it's a homework? I'd really rather try to solve it on my own if I were you. Besides, it's really as trivial as it gets. Anyway, see the updates.

Comment: Yep, in fact I have just solved it myself. I still accept your answer for your continued help. But I think you should take a look at this solution as well for it processes the string backwards instead `capitalised :: String->String
capitalised (x:[]) = [toUpper x] capitalised x = capitalised $ init x ++ [toLower $ last x] capitalised x = capitalised $ init x ++ [toLower $ last x]`

Comment: @oasisweng You'll get an awful performance with your proposed implementation, because both the `last` and the `init` operations require traversal of the whole list, in other words, they both have a time complexity of `O(n)`. Also you call those functions on each step of iteration, so summarily you get a time complexity of `O(n * (n + n))` for your function. A _cons_ operation (`:`) on the other hand has complexity of `O(1)`, so both my solutions have a resulting complexity of just `O(n)`.

Comment: Very well explained, tx!

Answer (score 9):

**Warning:** This solution is likely overkill, and not for newbies, but here's how to do it using traversals from the `lens` package.

```
import Control.Lens
import Data.Char

capitalize :: *really scary type would go here*
capitalize = over _head toUpper . over (_tail.each) toLower
```

Where `_head` and `_tail` are from `Control.Lens.Cons`, `each` is from `Control.Lens.Each`, and `over` is from `Control.Lens.Setter`.

The nice thing about this definition is that it should work with `Seq`, `Vector`, `Text` and other datatypes besides `String`, because they all are instances of [Cons](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.10/docs/Control-Lens-Cons.html#g:1) and [Each](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.10/docs/Control-Lens-Each.html). For example:

```
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Sequence as S

over _head toUpper . over (_tail.each) toLower $ "aA"
-- "Aa"
over _head toUpper . over (_tail.each) toLower $ T.pack "aA"
-- "Aa"
over _head toUpper . over (_tail.each) toLower $ S.fromList "aA"
-- "Aa"
```

**Edit:** Here's one more way to do it, just for the hell of it.

```
import Data.Char 
import Control.Lens 
import Control.Arrow (***)

over _Cons (toUpper *** over each toLower) "aA"
```

Comment: Would this be any less efficient than the solution @NikitaVolkov has given?  There's certainly more overhead, but a lot of that could theoretically be optimized out by the compiler since Lenses are almost built-in Haskell types.

Comment: @bheklilr It pattern-matches on the head of the list twice, instead of once. I don't know if `lens` introduces any significant overhead, perhaps it is optimized away.

Comment: Should be `import Control.Arrow ((***))`.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error on line:

```
| otherwise = capitalised (init x): map toLower (last x)
```

just use `head` and `tail`, not `init` and `last`:

```
capitalised [] = []
capitalised x = 
        | length x == 1 = map toUpper x
        | otherwise     = head (capitalised [head x]) : map toLower (tail x)
```

This solution is not optimal. Nikita Volkov's version is prettier.
Or we could rewrite it to

```
capitalised [] = []
capitalised x = toUpper (head x) : map toLower (tail x)
```

Comment: Advice for future readers: [Don't use `head`, `tail`, `init`, or `last`](http://siawyoung.com/coding/haskell/partial-functions-in-haskell-prelude.html).

Answer (score 0):

Couple more ways to do this, with the help of various libraries:

```
Prelude> :m +Data.Char Data.List
> let ucfirst x = (toUpper $ head x) : (toLower <$> tail x)

Prelude> :m +Data.Char Data.List Control.Arrow
> let ucfirst = (head >>> toUpper) &&& (tail >>> (toLower <$>)) >>> uncurry (:)

Prelude> :m +Data.Char Data.List Control.Applicative
> let ucfirst = liftA2 (:) (toUpper . head) ((toLower <$>) . tail)
```

They all do the same thing:

```
> ucfirst "fOO"
"Foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

Came here because I had to answer the same question, and came up with this solution

```
capitalised [] = []
capitalised xs  | length xs == 1 = capitalised (init xs) ++ [toUpper c | c<-xs]
                | otherwise = capitalised (init xs) ++ [toLower c | c<-xs, c == last xs]
```

Thought it was the most recursive answer accessible for beginners :)